# Swift: How to add dynamic text to CMSampleBuffer when using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput video recording?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on video recording by AVCaptureVideoDataOutput, and it works fine. Now I need to add dynamic text on the frame captured in captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer..(), and then save it by Avssetwriter. My current method is not working.

My current steps in captureOutput() are:
1. Convert the CMSampleBuffer to Pixelbuffer
2. New a UILabel with text
3. Convert the UILabel to UIImage
4. Using CIContext render function: render the UIImage to 
Pixelbuffer.

I'm sure the function of step 2 is OK. But if step 2 runs in captureOutput(), the crash will happen.

Any suggestion about adding text on CMSampleBuffer is welcome. Swift is better.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Your steps are basically correct. In step 4, though, use a CGContext instead of a CIContext, like this:

```
func write(image overlayImage:UIImage, toBuffer sample:CMSampleBuffer){
    let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sample)
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
    var bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue
    bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue & CGBitmapInfo.alphaInfoMask.rawValue
    let context = CGContext(data: CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!), width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer!), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer!), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer!), space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)
    context?.draw(overlayImage.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: overlayImage.size.width, height: overlayImage.size.height))
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
}
```

Comment: it doesn't change anything and what exactly does it do? why this function doesn't return new `CMSampleBuffer`?

Comment: the problem `context` == `nil` (`let context = CGContext(data: CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!), width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer!), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer!), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer!), space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)`)

Comment: It modifies the sample buffer that is passed in

Comment: it's not being modified, cause `context == nil`  always

Comment: Put a breakpoint in to figure out why the initializer is returning null then

Comment: can you please add an example on github how it works with camera?

Comment: anyone? How to add dynamic data to video like gps coordinates ?